# Aligning input textboxes using the width

Tags: html, css

I have the following input textboxes, but I have aligned them in css with {width: xxx px;} which is not a good practice as it will not always align correctly.

```
<style>
#left_col p {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.notvis {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#ws_doc_txt {
    width: 350px;
}
#ws_end_txt {
    width: 358px;
}
#ws_ns_txt {
    width: 340px;
}
#ws_op_txt {
    width: 25%;
}
#left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#right_col {
    margin: 0 0 0 500px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#textarea1 {
    text-align: left;
}
#button1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.greentxt {
    color: green;
}
.redtxt {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="left_col">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="WSDL" id="ws_type_0">
      WSDL</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="NOWSDL" id="ws_type_1">
      Endpoint</label>
  </p>
  <p id="ws_doc">
    <label for="ws_doc">Document:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_doc" id="ws_doc_txt">
  </p>
  <p id="ws_end">
    <label for="ws_end">Endpoint:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_end" id="ws_end_txt">
  </p>
  <p id="ws_ns">
    <label for="ws_ns">Namespace:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_ns" id="ws_ns_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_op">Operation:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_op" id="ws_op_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_par">Parameter:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_par" id="ws_par_txt">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ws_val">Value:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ws_val" id="ws_val_txt">
  </p>
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test">
</div>
```

What would be the correct way to make the width of the textboxes always stop at a certain point on the right side? Also, is using `<p>` tags to make inputs behave like block elements wrong? Could I just use css to have them stay 1 at each line? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a table to have all inputs aligned on the left side. Giving all inputs the same width should then align them perfectly on the right as well.

```css
#left_table input {
  width:350px;
}
```

```html
<table id="left_table">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="ws_doc">Document:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ws_doc" id="ws_doc_txt">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="ws_end">Endpoint:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ws_end" id="ws_end_txt">
  </tr>
  <!-- etc... -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all your text boxes to have the same attribute with proper positioning you can try this(obviously set proper values):

```
input[type='text'] 
{
   width: 270px;
   height: 30px;
   top: 167px;
   left: 43px;
   position:relative;
   margin-left: 10px;
   background-color: #F3F3F3;
   border: 1px solid #D6D6C2;
   border-radius: 3px;
```

}